# SABRE: Create PNR API Error: ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR

Tags: sabre

I'm building a web app and was integrating Sabre with it. I was following the "Low Fare Search and Book" workflow and I'm done shopping flights using Bargain Finder Max so I wanted to book the flights selected through Create Passenger Name Record. I'm stuck in sending Create PNR Request. I was consuming Create Passenger Name Record with the following payloads:

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "targetCity": "G1OJ",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": true,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "AgencyInfo": {
        "Address": {
          "AddressLine": "UNIT 707 PRINCE GREGORY CONDO 12TH AVENUE, CUBAO",
          "CityName": "QUEZON CITY",
          "CountryCode": "PH",
          "PostalCode": "1109",
          "StreetNmbr": "#105"
        },
        "Ticketing": {
          "TicketType": "7TAW"
        }
      },
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": [
            {
              "NameNumber": "1.1",
              "Phone": "639053314785",
              "PhoneUseType": "H"
            },
            {
              "NameNumber": "2.1",
              "Phone": "639053314785",
              "PhoneUseType": "H"
            }
          ]
        },
        "PersonName": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "ERWIN",
            "Surname": "PLAZA"
          },
          {
            "NameNumber": "2.1",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "AMABELLE",
            "Surname": "PLAZA"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirBook": {
      "HaltOnStatus": [
        {
          "Code": "HL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "KK"
        },
        {
          "Code": "LL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NN"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NO"
        },
        {
          "Code": "UC"
        },
        {
          "Code": "US"
        }
      ],
      "OriginDestinationInformation": {
        "FlightSegment": [
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2019-01-28T11:40:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2019-01-28T10:35:00",
            "FlightNumber": "1853",
            "NumberInParty": "2",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "T",
            "Status": "NN",
            "InstantPurchase": true,
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "CEB"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "PR",
              "FlightNumber": "1853"
            },
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "MNL"
            }
          },
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2019-01-30T23:05:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2019-01-30T21:50:00",
            "FlightNumber": "2880",
            "NumberInParty": "2",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "T",
            "Status": "NN",
            "InstantPurchase": true,
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "MNL"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "PR",
              "FlightNumber": "2880"
            },
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "CEB"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "RedisplayReservation": true,
      "ARUNK": "please do the arunk thing",
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "MOSCONI"
        }
      },
      "PostBookingHKValidation": {
        "waitInterval": 100,
        "numAttempts": 6
      },
      "WaitForAirlineRecLoc": {
        "waitInterval": 100,
        "numAttempts": 6
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I believe I provided the 5 mandatory elements in creating a PNR. 
**P** Phone Number
**R** Received From
**I** Itinerary
**N** Name of Traveler
**T** Ticketing Time Limit

However, I still get this Error

```
"Error": [
    {
     "type": "Application",
     "timeStamp": "2019-01-24T02:05:47.767-06:00",
     "SystemSpecificResults": [
        {
           "Message": [
             {
               "code": "ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR",
               "content": "Unable to perform air booking step"
              }
           ]
        }
      ]
```

What am I missing on my payload?

Comment: I believe that means that your webservices account is set to TEST. It must be set to PROD to be able to book. Contact Sabre Webservies support to have them switch it to PROD

Comment: But I'm just starting to build my application, should I need to be in PROD environment to test Create PNR API? I'm using this endpoint for sending this request: https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.1.0/passenger/records?mode=create. I believe this is a test environment endpoint.. However when I change to Prod environment endpoint I receive an authorization error.

Comment: I think you have 2 issues.
StreetNumber for Agency should start numeric - remove # character.
You are missing TicketTimeLimit under Ticketing

Comment: @ImranMomin I tried, but still get the same error. I addressed this issue to sabre customer support. and they said it is caused of missing keyword on our EPR that should be set by our account manager. Still waiting for our account manager response to hopefully resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Try to use this structure, I did notice your Json is missing some steps:
>   CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ, TravelItineraryAddInfo, AirBook AirPrice(***Required***), MiscSegment, SpecialReqDetails, PostProcessing

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "targetCity": "G7HE",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": true,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "AgencyInfo": {
        "Address": {
          "AddressLine": "My corp",
          "CityName": "SOUTHLAKE",
          "CountryCode": "US",
          "PostalCode": "76092",
          "StateCountyProv": {
            "StateCode": "TX"
          },
          "StreetNmbr": "9000 street corp"
        },
        "Ticketing": {
          "TicketType": "7TAW"
        }
      },
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": [
            {
              "NameNumber": "1.1",
              "Phone": "001-222-1111",
              "PhoneUseType": "H"
            },
            {
              "NameNumber": "2.1",
              "Phone": "111-111-1111",
              "PhoneUseType": "W"
            }
          ]
        },
        "CreditCardData": {
          "BillingInformation": {
            "cardHolderName": "SP TEST",
            "streetAddress": "2323, Hommer J Simpson",
            "city": "NEW YORK",
            "stateOrProvince": "NY",
            "PostalCode": "V9B0L2"
          }
        },
        "PersonName": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "NameReference": "ABC123",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "Hommer",
            "Surname": "Simpson"
          },
          {
            "NameNumber": "2.1",
            "NameReference": "DEF456",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "Bart",
            "Surname": "Simpson"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirBook": {
      "HaltOnStatus": [
        {
          "Code": "HL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "KK"
        },
        {
          "Code": "LL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NN"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NO"
        },
        {
          "Code": "UC"
        },
        {
          "Code": "US"
        }
      ],
      "OriginDestinationInformation": {
        "FlightSegment": [
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-09-10T19:14:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2018-09-10T11:35:00",
            "FlightNumber": "745",
            "NumberInParty": "2",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "W",
            "Status": "NN",
            "InstantPurchase": true,
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "DTW"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "DL",
              "FlightNumber": "745"
            },
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "SFO"
            }
          },
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-09-10T20:59:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2018-09-10T19:55:00",
            "FlightNumber": "2010",
            "NumberInParty": "2",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "W",
            "Status": "NN",
            "InstantPurchase": true,
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "MCI"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "DL",
              "FlightNumber": "2010"
            },
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "DTW"
            }
          },
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-09-17T18:50:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2018-09-17T17:10:00",
            "FlightNumber": "1076",
            "NumberInParty": "2",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "W",
            "Status": "NN",
            "InstantPurchase": true,
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "MSP"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "DL",
              "FlightNumber": "1076"
            },
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "MCI"
            }
          },
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-09-18T00:13:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2018-09-17T20:15:00",
            "FlightNumber": "2214",
            "NumberInParty": "2",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "W",
            "Status": "NN",
            "InstantPurchase": true,
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "JFK"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "DL",
              "FlightNumber": "2214"
            },
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "MSP"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirPrice": [
      {
        "PriceComparison": [
          {
            "AmountSpecified": 1000,
            "AcceptablePriceIncrease": {
              "HaltOnNonAcceptablePrice": false,
              "Amount": 500
            }
          }
        ],
        "PriceRequestInformation": {
          "Retain": true,
          "OptionalQualifiers": {
            "FOP_Qualifiers": {
              "BasicFOP": {
                "Type": "CK"
              }
            },
            "PricingQualifiers": {
              "NameSelect": [
                {
                  "NameNumber": "1.1"
                }
              ],
              "PassengerType": [
                {
                  "Code": "ADT",
                  "Quantity": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "PriceComparison": [
          {
            "AmountSpecified": 1000,
            "AcceptablePriceDecrease": {
              "HaltOnNonAcceptablePrice": false,
              "Percent": 500
            }
          }
        ],
        "PriceRequestInformation": {
          "Retain": true,
          "OptionalQualifiers": {
            "FOP_Qualifiers": {
              "BasicFOP": {
                "Type": "CK"
              }
            },
            "PricingQualifiers": {
              "NameSelect": [
                {
                  "NameNumber": "2.1"
                }
              ],
              "PassengerType": [
                {
                  "Code": "ADR",
                  "Quantity": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "MiscSegment": {
      "VendorPrefs": {
        "Airline": {
          "Code": "AS"
        }
      },
      "DepartureDateTime": "09-13",
      "NumberInParty": 2,
      "Text": "TEST OTH MISCELLANEOUS SEGMENT",
      "Type": "OTH",
      "OriginLocation": {
        "LocationCode": "ORD"
      },
      "Status": "GK"
    },
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
      "AddRemark": {
        "RemarkInfo": {
          "FOP_Remark": {
            "Type": "CHECK"
          }
        }
      },
      "SpecialService": {
        "SpecialServiceInfo": {
          "SecureFlight": [
            {
              "SegmentNumber": "A",
              "PersonName": {
                "DateOfBirth": "2001-01-01",
                "Gender": "M",
                "NameNumber": "1.1",
                "GivenName": "Hommer",
                "Surname": "Simpson"
              },
              "VendorPrefs": {
                "Airline": {
                  "Hosted": false
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "SegmentNumber": "A",
              "PersonName": {
                "DateOfBirth": "2002-02-02",
                "Gender": "M",
                "NameNumber": "2.1",
                "GivenName": "Bart",
                "Surname": "Simpson"
              },
              "VendorPrefs": {
                "Airline": {
                  "Hosted": false
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "Service": [
            {
              "SSR_Code": "VGML",
              "Text": "CC Hommer Simpson"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "RedisplayReservation": true,
      "ARUNK": "please do the arunk thing",
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "SP TEST"
        }
      },
      "PostBookingHKValidation": {
        "waitInterval": 100,
        "numAttempts": 6
      },
      "WaitForAirlineRecLoc": {
        "waitInterval": 100,
        "numAttempts": 6
      }
    }
  }
}
```